# Django, get initials data from field in formset with shell

Tags: python, django, shell, django-forms, formset

I'm using formset in Django 1.11, and in template rendering all works done. 
Now I want test formset in python shell.
So I make a simple form and then a formset (2) with initials data:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class my_formset(forms.Form):
...    my_field_1=forms.IntegerField()
...    my_field_2=forms.IntegerField()
... 

>>> values=[{'my_field_1':10,'my_field_2':15}, {'my_field_1':84,'my_field_2':6}]

>>> values
   [{'my_field_2': 15, 'my_field_1': 10}, {'my_field_2': 6, 'my_field_1': 84}]
```

Building formset:

```
>>> from django.forms import formset_factory
>>> formset=formset_factory(my_formset,extra=0)
>>> my_data_fs=formset(initial=values)
```

Result formset:

```
 >>> my_data_fs
 <django.forms.formsets.my_formsetFormSet object at 0x7fdb688dda90>
 >>> my_data_fs.forms
 [<my_formset bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(my_field_1;my_field_2)>,   <my_formset bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(my_field_1;my_field_2)>]
```

Now I want get initials data:

```
>>> my_data_fs.forms[0]
<my_formset bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(my_field_1;my_field_2)>
>>> my_data_fs.forms[0].fields
OrderedDict([('my_field_1', <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x7fdb688dd7b8>), ('my_field_2', <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x7fdb688dd710>)])
```

but if I see single field, I  get this:

```
>>> my_data_fs.forms[0].fields['my_field_1']
<django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at 0x7fdb688dd7b8>
>>> my_data_fs.forms[0].fields['my_field_1'].value
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'value'
```

And if I use initials I get empty response

```
>>> my_data_fs.forms[0].fields['my_field_1'].initial
>>>
```

What I have to do for get my initials data?

Comment: You are sure that value attribute should be available ? hasattr(my_data_fs.forms[0].fields['my_field_1'], 'value') == False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You are looking after is probably this:

`print(my_data_fs.forms[0].initial)`

In that way You can access initial data on unbound form

Check out what is the difference between fields on bound and unbound form
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#module-django.forms

From documentation it is clear that in order to access data

 `print(bound_form['subject'].data)`

the form must be initialized with **data** keyword in other words bounded, but if You only want to access initial data, You can still do it on unbound form as I did in the first code example.

Comment: Python will never turn its' back on You, so whenever You have an AttributeError, check if what You are looking for is really there :), Cheers